# Redistribute MS Word as a part of application

Tags: winforms, ms-word

I need to provide an editor as a part of my application. 
The MS Word lends itself as a most convenient one but the GUI customization API in versions above 2003 is not flexible enough for my needs. So it has to be Word 2003. All my users have MS Office 
installed but many of them have version 2007 and 2010. I want to setup MS Word 2003 as a part of my 
application. Office 2007 or 2010 and 2003 function well side by side so no problem here.
But the question is: Is it legal? Can I add the MS Word 2003 setup MSI to my installation package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to legally distribute MS Word 2003. Are you writing a Windows Forms application? If so, why not use the RichTextBox widget as part of your app?

Answer (score 0):

It's not legal, if you readed the License whe you install it, you should know that redistribuitable (i think it's mispelled) is not an option.

Sorry, you should find another way

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is No. This isn't legal. A possible recourse is to use COM+ or DCOM.